# how to work 2 backgroundworker simultaneously?

Tags: c#, .net

i have a little bit problem about backgroundworkers. i have 2 class and i want to work them simultaneously.

```
private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker bg1,bg2 ;

private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
{
    bg1= new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    bg1.DoWork +=new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(bg1_DoWork);

    bg2 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    bg2.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(bg2_DoWork);
}

private void bg1_DoWork(object sender,System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    p myp = (p)e.Argument;
    myp.solver();
    quantities = myp.dizi_ata(myp.miktarlar);
    sonuc_listele(myp.miktarlar, myp.maliyet, myp.toplam_ceza,"P");
}

private void bg2_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    a mya = (a)e.Argument;
    mya.solver();
    quantities = mya.dizi_ata(mya.miktarlar);
    sonuc_listele(mya.miktarlar, mya.maliyet, mya.toplam_ceza, "ABC");
}
```

and,I call these backgroundworker like below code

```
try        
{
    InitializeBackgroundWorker();
    if (!bg1.IsBusy && !bg2.IsBusy)
    {
        bg1.RunWorkerAsync(myp);
        bg2.RunWorkerAsync(mya);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

when i try this code, bg2 dont work(dont give result) but bg1 work and give result. How can i fix this problem?
Please give me an example about this problem or fix my code.
thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see any problems with this. How are you determining that only one of these is being called. Put some logging statements (`Debug.WriteLine`) in your DoWork methods and you'll probably see that they're both being called.

Comment: @akifsahman How your workers return the results to the main thread?

Comment: Wild guess: Both methods are setting the value of `quantities` and `bg2` is overwriting what `bg1` had previously set? Which may be why you're seeing `bg2` providing a result, but not `bg1`?

Comment: Dear Micheal, both of Dowork function works when i call 2 backgroundworks. When bg1 working , bg1 compose class myp. after in bg1_DoWork function myp produce result(myp.miktarlar). I mean myp return me mya.miktarlar values.Eventhough bg2 take arguments but dont return me result (mya.miktarlar).

Comment: Dear Alex, when myp.solver() code works class return myp.miktarlar and also mya.solver() return mya.miktarlar. But when i looked and follow lines mya.solver() class dont work so dont give me result :(

Comment: I have solved problem dear friends :) Problem was in my class. But thank you again about your valuable helps.

Answer (score 1):

Store the result of each worker on a separate variable, in this case **quantities_bg1** and **quantities_bg1**

```
private void bg1_DoWork(object sender,System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    p myp = (p)e.Argument;
    myp.solver();
    quantities_bg1 = myp.dizi_ata(myp.miktarlar);
    sonuc_listele(myp.miktarlar, myp.maliyet, myp.toplam_ceza,"P");
}

private void bg2_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    a mya = (a)e.Argument;
    mya.solver();
    quantities_bg2 = mya.dizi_ata(mya.miktarlar);
    sonuc_listele(mya.miktarlar, mya.maliyet, mya.toplam_ceza, "ABC");
}
```

And also you potentially have a memory leak since you always initialize the workers even if you dont start them

```
try        
{
    if(bg1 == null)
    {
        InitializeBackgroundWorker();
    }

    if ((bg1 != null) && (!bg1.IsBusy))
    {
        bg1.RunWorkerAsync(myp);
    }

    if ((bg2 != null) && (!bg2.IsBusy))
    {
        bg2.RunWorkerAsync(mya);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: `InitializeBackgroundWorker()` should check if bg1/bg2 is null before setting the values. However, this probably isn't the problem since `bg2` is doing work. I suspect the issue is both bg methods are setting the value of `quantities`... see my comment to OP.

Comment: quantities is global variable but i will try.

Answer (score 1):

If your final answer relies on the result AFTER both background workers are finished, then it may be that whoever finished last, wins with respect to your quantities field.  I think you may be close on your task, but might offer this adjustment.  Create two fields to hold each result respectively, and at the end of BOTH processes being complete, then do whatever else by hooking up to the RunWorkerCompleted event.

```
// Add fields first...
int BG1_Qty;
int BG2_Qty;

// add flag fields to CONFIRM a step is done
bool BG1_Finished;
bool BG2_Finished;

private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
{
    bg1= new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    bg1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(bg1_DoWork);

    bg2 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    bg2.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(bg2_DoWork);

    // have BOTH background workers call same "I'm Finished" method when they are done
    bg1.RunWorkerCompleted += TasksFinished;
    bg2.RunWorkerCompleted += TasksFinished;

    // NOW Run them BOTH
    bg1.RunWorkerAsync();
    bg2.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void bg1_DoWork(object sender,System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    p myp = (p)e.Argument;
    myp.solver();
    BG1_Qty = myp.dizi_ata(myp.miktarlar);
    sonuc_listele(myp.miktarlar, myp.maliyet, myp.toplam_ceza,"P");
    BG1_Finished = true;
}

private void bg2_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    a mya = (a)e.Argument;
    mya.solver();
    BG2_Qty = mya.dizi_ata(mya.miktarlar);
    sonuc_listele(mya.miktarlar, mya.maliyet, mya.toplam_ceza, "ABC");
    BG2_Finished = true;
}

private void TasksFinished(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   // since BOTH background workers will call this method when they complete,
   // all we need to do is look at the flags... whoever wins first, it will not
   // do anything, but when the SECOND finishes, it will.
   if( BG1_Finished &&  BG2_Finished)
   {
      quantities = BG1_Qty + BG2_Qty;
   }
}
```

The obvious end "TaskFinished" may not be what you want, but shows principle of you should now be able to see BOTH answers when BOTH are finished.

Comment: quantities not important for me in this case. i have looked code when i try code mya take arguments but mya class dont work and dont produce result :(((

Comment: how are you detecting that no output or result is produced ? do you debug ? do you write to a file or modify a database ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia, I don't, you will need to analyze based on your running.  All I was doing was also calling a RunWorkerCompleted event.  When each individual processes its values, it sets the flag as finished.  Then, in the RunWorkerCompleted event, it only processed when BOTH flags are marked as finished.  It does not indicate if you have no values returned, but I can't confirm what I can not see.